# DropzoneJs success and error callback

Tags: angularjs, callback, dropzone.js

I'm building an AngularJs app and I'm using a dropzone from DropzoneJs. I need to use the success and error callback because I have to access to the server response. I'm having a problem that if I use the callbacks, the previewTemplate changes... So, can I change the previewTemplate inside the callback?

If I don't use the callbacks here's the result template and the code:

[image: no callbakcs success][image: no callbacks error]

```
var myDropzone = $("#storageDropzone").dropzone({
    url: firstUrl,        
});
```

If I use the callbacks the "tick" or the "cross" don't show up:

[image: with callback success][image: with callback error]

```
var myDropzone = $("#storageDropzone").dropzone({
    url: firstUrl,
    error: function (file, response) {
        console.log("Erro");
        console.log(response);
    },
    success: function (file, response) {
        console.log("Sucesso");
        console.log(response);
    },
    complete: function (file) {
        console.log("Complete");
    }
});
```

So, can I change the previewTemplate inside the callbacks? or simply, keep the one that exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, this is the workaround I found...

Instead of using the callbacks, I make the changes on the init function. Although this answer doesn't satisfy me, it's the best I can do for now... If anyone can explain why it works on the init but not as a callback feel free to answer.

This is the solution:

```
var myDropzone = $("#storageDropzone").dropzone({
    init: function () {
        this.on("processing", function (file) {
            $scope.$apply($scope.working = true);
            this.options.url = lastUrl;
            $scope.$apply($scope.processing = true);
        });

        this.on("success", function (file, response) {
            console.log("sucesso");
            var ficheiro = { nome: file.name, link: response[0] };
            $scope.$apply($scope.uploadedFiles.push(ficheiro));
        });

        this.on("error", function (file, error, xhr) {
            var ficheiro = { nome: file.name, status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText, erro: error.message };
            $scope.$apply($scope.errorFiles.push(ficheiro));
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is that since you are overriding the default DropZone "error" and "success" callback functions, the "tick" and "cross" are not created on the file upload tiles. It isn't that the template is changed; you are overriding the default DropZone error and success behaviors. For the "tick" and "cross" to show up, you would need to copy the code from the default DropZone error and success callback functions into your functions, then implement whatever additional or changed behavior you need.